# iphone gwtphonegap Geolocation always on

Tags: iphone, gwt, cordova, geolocation

on **gwtphonegap 1.7.0.0** (iPhone) i use the geolocation service to get the user's position only once in the beginning on the application

```
    GeolocationOptions options = new GeolocationOptions();
    options.setMaximumAge(1000);
    options.setEnableHighAccuracy(true);
    phoneGap.getGeolocation().getCurrentPosition(callback, options);
```

the call is made only once in the beginning and no update of the position is needed afterwards.

The problem is that when I run my application on iPhone, the GPS indicator on the status bar stays on all the time, even after I get the correct position. 
This may cause a useless battery usage.

Is there a way to tell the Geolocation service to stop after it gets the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like we are missing the routines from the gwt phonegap implementation. I just rechecked and they are not part of the docs.

I just posted an issue with the gwt-phonegap project: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/issues/detail?id=57

As a workaround you can drop to jsni and call the start / stop method directly.

Comment: any idea how to do that ?
I tried something like
 `public static native String stopGeolocation() /*-{
   Geolocation.prototype.stop();
 }-*/;`
but i'm not sure what's the method to call.
Thank you

Comment: OK this one works just fine:
`public static native String stopGeolocation() /*-{
  if (typeof $wnd.device != "undefined"
    && typeof $wnd.cordova == "object") {
   $wnd.cordova.exec("Geolocation.stopLocation");
  }
 }-*/;`

Answer (score 1):

The underlying phonegap library seems to have [start() and stop() methods](https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/blob/master/iphone/PhoneGapLib/javascripts/core/geolocation.js). You may have to extend gwtphonegap.